# Set slice horizontal and vertical constraints

Tags: dm-script, line-plot

Are there script commands to manipulate "Horizontal/Vertical Constraints" of slices in a line plot image display?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44807390/1302888)

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately these features are not exposed to the scripting language. (Status GMS 3.2)